# Position 2 absolute DIV inside 1 relative DIV within bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I am trying to position 2 divs within 1 div inside a bootstrap container... One located top left and one located top right.

I can get the one top left to sit where I want it to, but the bottom right one, when putting `right: 20px` sits to the right of the browser itself, and not within the container.

Here is my HTML & CSS:

```
<div id="header">
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
        Top left content
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        Bottom right content
    </div>
</div>
</div>

#header {
height: 625px;
position: relative;
}

#header .div1 {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
}

#header .div2 {
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
right: 20px;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get the bottom right div to sit to the right of the container and not the browser, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did you look if bootstrap overwrites your position: relative of the container? than you have to set it !important

Comment: Hi @RudiUrbanek, thanks for replying... I did give that a go, but it still sits to the far right of the browser.

Comment: I've just checked, and it doesn't seem to be overridden (for me, at least) by the Bootstrap CSS. On a similar note, @user3642210, could you just clarify that your own CSS is loaded *after* Bootstraps (they're done top-down in order) when you're referencing your `link rel="stylesheet"...`s in the page's header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your absolute divs are placed inside the `#header` element since you applied `position:relative` on it.

Bootstrap doesn't have explicitly set relative position for container class. You need to set position for container and then your absolute divs will be placed inside the container:

```
.container{
  position: relative;
}
```

So, it would be good to replace the following:

```
#header {
   height: 625px;
   position: relative;
}
```

With this:

```
#header .container{
   height: 625px;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I just gave this a try, and unfortunately did not work.

Comment: When removing bottom: 20px, this sits to the right as I want, but it sits at the top, not the bottom. As soon as I added bottom: 20px back, it seems to disappear altogether!

Comment: Its because you don't have height set in the container. Just try the updated answer.

Comment: You little guru! Thank you @Bhojendra Nepal !

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#header {
height: 625px;
position: relative;
}

#header .div1 {
float: left;
top: 20;
}

#header .div2 {
position: absolute;
bottom: 20;
right: 0;
}
</style>

<div id="header">
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
        Top left content
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        Bottom right content
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation @Rahul - *slow hand clap...*

Comment: @RahulMukati I like this concept, but the float right does not sit the bottom right div? I know setting a margin-top can be done, but is this the correct way to do so?

Comment: @user3642210 - Code Updated! Try Now... ! div1 is at top-left and div2 is bottom-right